# Show that $|sin(x)+cos(x)|$ is continuous at $\pi$

Tags: continuity

Show that the function $f(x)= |\sin(x)+\cos(x)|$ is continuous at $x=\pi$.

By drawing the graph, we can easily show that it is continuous, but how can we show it by using limits. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? It is ggod to show what you have tried so far to get good responses.

Comment: How about as a composite of continuous function?

Comment: $\sin x$, $\cos x$ and $\left| x \right|$ are all continuous. So $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: The number defined as the ratio between the diameter and circumference of a circle is called $\pi$, a greek letter which is spelled pi, often pronounced as pie, but please don't spell it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proven in a number of ways. Firstly as Olivier Begassat noted that it is a composition of continues functions and thus is continues itself. 
Another way you can see it is by observing that: 
$$\lim_{x\downarrow \pi} f(x)=|\sin(\pi)+\cos(\pi)|=\lim_{x\uparrow \pi}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \pi}f(x)=1$$ So the function exists and is well defined in the limit. Therefore it is conitnues